# What's the amount of heat flowing to this system?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

Im stuck trying to understand the solution to this question.

Q: A thermodynamic system is defined by the equations - $P^2V = aNK_bT$, where $a>0$ and N>0 are constants. what is the amount of heat Q flowing into the system during a isothermal reversible expansion at temprature $T_0$ from initial pressure $2P_0$ to $P_0$?

A: [image]

What I don't understand is why $Tds = T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial P}\right)_{T,N}$ ?

How would I have find this relation? Isn't $ds $ just $\frac{1}{T}dU + \frac{P}{T}dV $?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$dS=\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_PdT+\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial P}\right)_TdP$$ But, dT=0.

Comment: Thanks! Can you help me understand where this equation is coming from?

Comment: Do you mean the equation I wrote?

Comment: yeah, i would like to understand its derivation because I'm only familiar with ds = du/T +pdv/T. (a link to where i can read about it would also suffice).

Comment: The equation I wrote is just a mathematical relationship that applies if S = S(T,P).

Comment: Could we do this with any two variables other then T and P or are there some constraints?

Comment: Well, you could do it using T and V.

Comment: Ok, I haven't understood completely but i bugged you enough. Thank you!

Comment: If you want to discuss this in greater detail, go to physicsforums.com, thermodynamics subforum of Classical Physics.